# What is the role of consensus algorithm in hyperledger blockchain network? How does it works?

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, consensus, hyperledger-sawtooth

How does consensus algorithm in hyperledger blockchain work?

Have all nodes access to the same chain code? If yes, what is the role of consensus then? And how does it works?

Answer (score 3):

First be aware that there are different, independent Hyperledger blockchain platforms, including Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Sawtooth.

For Hyperledger Sawtooth, and for blockchain software in general, the consensus algorithm decides who has the right to publish the next block in the blockchain (who becomes the "leader").  For traditional public blockchains (such as Bitcoin), the consensus algorithm is Proof of Work (PoW). That is, the node that solves a cryptographic puzzle first (generates a SHA-256 hash with the most leading 0s) wins the right to publish the next block. Unfortunately PoW is extremely wasteful of energy and active research is involved in developing new consensus algorithms.

Comment: I asked the same question before, and I did not get my answer. I think the main question is about transaction processing not block producing (If I'm wrong, please tell me).  
Here is the problem, what will happen if some of the validators malfunction?  
Suppose a transaction with input `A` is sent to `validator1` which set a `B` value in the state of `validator1`. Same transaction set `C` on the state of `validator2`.  
Here we have two validators with different states and next transactions will never be committed. The consensus will become broken.

Comment: The transactions are signed and cannot be modified by the validator.
Assuming a transaction processor has a bug and sets an invalid value (validator2). The other nodes will not accept new blocks from that validator node, as the transaction(s) in the new block will fail verification. The other nodes will continue to accept new transactions and add new blocks without the broken validator.

Answer (score -1):

In Hyper ledger fabric, consensus is achieved by three steps -

Endorsement, 
Ordering, and 
Validation.

You are talking about the first step that is endorsement.

If I get you correctly you are saying that if all the nodes have the same code then they will naturally give the same result after execution of the chain code, then why do we need consensus in the first place. In fact this is exactly why we need the consensus, we have to make sure that the result of the majority of the nodes is correct in order to eliminate any incorrect results (from the node which might be compromised).

have a detailed look here https://www.skcript.com/svr/consensus-hyperledger-fabric/

Comment: Please, let me rephrase what I understood from your answer .. The role of consensus algorithm is to provide a protection for the blockchain network against any security attacks or against any intentional modifications of the chaincode by one of peers .. Is this correct?!

Comment: partially, and that too in the endorsement step of the process.